# What is the performance limitation of a javafx scatter plot?

Tags: charts, plot, javafx, javafx-2, scatter

Can anyone tell me how many points a JavaFX scatter chart can display? The charts can be seen [here](http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/javafx-2-0-charts).

The charts look great, but just wondering about performance.

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't JavaFX based on a scene graph? Does the chart handle overlapping points automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isn't JavaFX based on a scene graph?`

It is.

`ScatterChart` points are all stack panes. ([reference](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/2.2/controls/rt/file/7c3dc5904604/javafx-ui-charts/src/javafx/scene/chart/ScatterChart.java)) All of the specified points are added to the scene. They can be animated. Even when the points are overlapping they are added separately. So you see the point which is added last.

I haven't tested the performance. If you use this chart to show a constant set of data, then I would recommend to turn on caching on this chart. Which makes a bitmap and does not render it so often.

If you have a large set of data, plot it on a Canvas. (Which is now and was not when you asked)